# How To Add string between two item php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string-concatenation

For example I have the following PHP code:

```
 $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, "SELECT nama_lengkap, keterangan   FROM Absensi WHERE DATE(tanggal_kirim)=CURDATE() ORDER BY tanggal_kirim");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $comma = ",";

foreach(  $row as $key=>$value )
   {
       $csv_output .= $comma . $value;
       $comma = "";
   }
   $csv_output .= "\n";
}

print $csv_output;
exit;
```

The Question i want add string between 'nama_lengkap' 'keterangan' So the output will be nama_lengkap (keterangan)

Comment: You have to do it after fetching value and the time you are going to show the record in form of table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do in directly in SQL by using the `concat` function:

```sql
SELECT   CONCAT(nama_lengkap, '(', keterangan, ')')   
FROM     Absensi 
WHERE    DATE(tanggal_kirim) = CURDATE() 
ORDER BY tanggal_kirim
```

Or in PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, "SELECT nama_lengkap, keterangan   FROM Absensi WHERE DATE(tanggal_kirim)=CURDATE() ORDER BY tanggal_kirim");
$str = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $str = $row['nama_lengkap'] . '(' . $row['keterangan'] . ')';
    // use $str somehow
}
```

Comment: Hm... Stack's syntax highlighter's showing something's off.

Comment: ah found it `['nama_lengkap]` missing quote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just noticed myself and fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: *Ah,* a green ticky; *nice*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, just add one line instead *for* loop. Thats it.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
   $comma = ",";

   $csv_output .= $comma . $row["nama_lengkap"] . "(" . $row["keterangan"] . ")"; //This line instead of for loop

   $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```